# Products are not alligned properly in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I am using `Magento 1.9.0.1.` I successfully installed and add products to my site. But the problem is that the products are not displayed in a correct order. That is 2 products in 1 row, 1 product in another row. Products are not alligned properly.

Please refer the image below.

[image]

How can I allign product properly, i need 2 products in each row as normal. The images of products used is have the same dimension. That is each image is `142 X 142`.

This happens in `chrome, IE, mozilla firefox.`

I followed this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9  for display product in home page.

Any help is really appreciable..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the `default` theme. Please change the theme and check whether the issue is exist or not. I think for different theme the problem should not come.

**Note**: This is not the answer you want i know.. But this is only a suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

If product result is ok then you need to only manage css. you need change css make image product smaller and reduce width of product it will automatically display 3 product in each row.